# logistic regression sample size calculation

Tags: logistic, sample-size

I m trying to find if parental involvement can positively impact student's 4 year graduation rate.
My target variable is student's graduation (yes / no)
Main independent variable is whether parent attended first year orientation(yes / no)
I am also considering other independent variables as sex, in/out of state, admitted time, major..etc.

In this case, how can I calculate sample size?

1. Should I decide variables first or calculate sample size first?
2. Some equation include Odds ration in sample size calculation, but how can I know my OR at this point?
3. Do I have to complete collecting sample data and run some test(normality.. or whatever) in order to have all ingredients for calculating sample size?  - I have to request student data to univ department, that is why I am trying to get sample size before I send data request.

Please give me simple and clear explanation. Sadly, I won't be understand any theoretical statistics reasoning behind sample size equation.....

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Should I decide variables first or calculate sample size first?

You should decide on the variables you're going to study first.  Partly because the correlation of the other variables with the variable of interest will play a part in the sample size calculation.

> Some equation include Odds ration in sample size calculation, but how can I know my OR at this point?

When you do a sample size calculation, you design the study to have a pre-specified statistical power to detect a smallest odds ratio of interest.  If the true odds ratio is bigger, perfect you have additional power to detect.

The way to think about this is as follows: *what is the smallest odds ratio you would still be excited to tell your colleagues about*?

> Do I have to complete collecting sample data and run some test(normality.. or whatever) in order to have all ingredients for calculating sample size? - I have to request student data to univ department, that is why I am trying to get sample size before I send data request.

No need to have data in hand, but it helps.

Now, onto the calculation.

---

According to [this](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4614-1353-0) book (second edition, pg. 195) the sample size formula for logistic regression is

$$ n = \dfrac{(z_{1-\alpha/2} + z_{\gamma})^2}{(\beta\sigma_x)^2p(1-p)(1-\rho^2)} $$

Where

- $z_{1-\alpha/2}$ is the $1-\alpha/2$ percentile of a standard normal.  If you use $\alpha=0.05$ then $z_{1-\alpha/2} \approx 1.96$
- $\gamma$ is the desired power level and $z_\gamma$ the $\gamma^{th}$ quantile of a standard normal.  If you use 80% power then $z_\gamma \approx 0.84$
- $\beta$ is the smallest log odds ratio of interest.  Note I said LOG odds ratio.
- $\sigma_x$ is the standard deviation of the predictor you're studying.  Since the variable is binary (attended orientation, did not attend orientation) then this is going to be $\sqrt{f(1-f)}$, where $f$ is the fraction of the sample who had their parents come to orientation.  This just requires an educated guess, no need for this to be perfect.
- $p$ is the marginal prevalence of fourth year graduation.
- $\rho^2$ is the $R^2$ from a linear regression where the outcome is "Parent attended orientation" and the predictors are the other variables in your model.  This is the hardest to pin down.  Just try to think about how well correlated the predictor of interest is to the other variables.

Without any information on the proportion of students graduating, or the proportion of parents who come to orientation, I can't really help much further.

Comment: (I will happy +1 this when there is mention to the book name and the relevant chapter & page. I dislike it when people generally mention "book X" because going through hundreds of pages to find the referred passage is often very counterproductive. For the record, I checked the book and I *cannot* find this formula - but that book is *exceptional* and my search potential imperfect.)

Comment: @usεr11852. See the end of the logistic regression chapter.  The final section should be sample size calculations.  I don't have a page reference right now

Comment: it's not there I am afraid. (Assuming you refer to Chapter 6)

Comment: @usεr11852 [Here](https://imgur.com/YahiMgm) is a screenshot of the formula.  I'm not sure if we're looking at the same book, but it is most certainly there.

Comment: [Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/19aKl490bexLuKpXUd9htct9fEnIN5jmv/view?usp=share_link) is a link to the book I'm looking at.

Comment: Thank you for these clarification. Right, I was looking at version 1 of the book where the Logistic regression is Chapter 6, not 5 (judging on your screenshot) and that formula indeed isn't there. So it makes sense to give that information on your post as originally suggested in the comments to avoid these confusion. Even the book link doesn't have the version info (unless you click on the image of the hard cover).

Comment: @usεr11852 edited to add a page number and edition.

Comment: +1 but is there a reason why you don't say the book name?

Comment: @usεr11852 What additional information would the title provide that a hyperlink to the publisher's site for the book could not?  The only case I can think of is if the publisher were to, for example, release a new edition and the page were to 404.

Comment: Easier to find; I don't need a second web page; I can immediately see if I have already have that book. Think of it like me telling you "I read X in this book" and then I hold the book with a black sheet of paper infront of it. Well, sure you can move the paper out of the way very easily but me just saying "in book 'Advances of Y in Z' by Alice et al." is easier to qualify as a relevant resource.

Comment: Thank you so much!! I have question, for log of odds ratio of interest, when I calculate do I need to push 'log' or 'ln' button on calculator? statistics never specify which one to use when they have log in calculation...

Comment: Also, the marginal prevalence of 4th year graduation means students' graduation prevalence of who brought their parents at orientation? (Parents at orientation student graduate/total graduate)?

Comment: @김서연 First, use ln (the natural logarithm).  Second,p is the marginal prevalence of the outcome.  Estimate the fraction of students who graduate.  This is your estimate of p